# Installing SSL on Wordpress without Ciomand Line access and provider support

Tags: wordpress, ssl, openssl

I have a WP page without Command Line access, just FTP to copy files. My provider doesn't provide SSL support, is there a way to switch my page to SSL, so I can change to an e-store and handle payments?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloudflare free SSL and simple SSL plugin (to fix mixed content issues ) . The above will require switching the domain names to cloudflare's one

Comment: This is a paid service?

Comment: They provide a free plan with SSL (so it is FREE )